# How does yarn workspaces treat external dependencies with different versions?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Let's say a I have the following monorepo structure using Yarn workspaces:

```
node_modules
packages
  admin-app       // WEB APP FOR ADMIN DASHBOARD
  user-app        // PUBLIC WEB APP FOR REGULAR USERS
packages.json
```

Let's say both `admin-app` and `user-app` will need to install React as a dependency.

Here is what I'll do to add React on both workspaces:

```
yarn workspace admin-app add react
yarn workspace user-app add react
```

Currently, this results in both of my packages depending on `"react": "^17.0.2"`.

Inside my root `node_modules`, I can see that there is only one `react` folder in it. And the version is, as expected, `17.0.2`.

But what if at some point I update React on `admin-app` and maybe forget to update it on the `user-app`. How will `yarn` install those two different versions of React? For example: `17.0.5` and `17.0.2`?

Answer (score 2):

As a I writing this question I've decided to test it.

Here is what I did:

```
yarn workspace user-app add react           // THIS WILL INSTALL THE LATEST 17.0.2
yarn workspace admin-app add react@17.0.1
```

This was the result:

```
node_modules
  react v17.0.1
packages
  admin-app
  user-app
    node_modules
      react v17.0.2
```

Yarn chose to keep the older version `17.0.1` in the root `node_modules` folder, and it installed the `17.0.2` in the `user-app/node_modules` folder.